# How to reference a property from exact instance from another class?

Tags: swift, reference

I've found similar questions but none of the solutions seem to work.
This is my problem:

- I have a class, `GeneralPostAreaController: UIViewController`
- It has a property, "`queryObject`" which is defined as "`ParseQueryer()`" (custom class I created to get data objects)
- essentially "`queryObject`" stores data to create a post
- I have **another** class (which is also a separate file) , `PostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell`
- I want to reference "`queryObject`" inside `PostTableViewCell` so I can do actions with the data inside "`queryObject`"

Code below:

```
class GeneralPostAreaController: UIViewController {

    var queryObject = ParseQueryer()

    ...Other code here
```

In another file:

```
class PostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    //reference the queryObject here
```

Thank you! BTW I am also really new to programming and Swift.

Comment: While you can accompish this, you probably want to move your `ParseQueryer` out of your view controller, since it has little to do with controlling views. It would be more appropriate in a separate class dedicated to obtaining and storing data, which you could access for example as a singleton, or as a property on your app delegate.

Comment: yep....ended up having to refactor everything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution is let `queryObject` be a static variable.

```
class GeneralPostAreaController: UIViewController {
    static var queryObject = ParseQueryer()
}
```

Then, you can access `queryObject` anywhere in your application like this:

```
GeneralPostAreaController.queryObject
```